# How to block Apps Advertisements?

Tags: applications

I rooted my android device.

After rooting, is it possible to block or stop advertisements coming on apps?

If yes, please guide me for resolving this issue.

Regards

GNS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop advertizements, the best cure is an [Ad-Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker). I e.g. use [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway), which modifies Androids `hosts` file so "ad servers" are no longer found – while accessing other resources works fine.

As Ahmed pointed out, buying the full version of an app usually ends the ads in that app as well (and rewards the dev for the work done). So ad blockers are rather for the "left overs": apps which have no ad-free version, plus preventing other "evil stuff" (as possibly infected ads on websites).

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for replying me and resolving my concerns. I understand that full version of an app usually ends the apps but in some cases like News Apps or Classified Apps, it’s not true. AdAway requires root permission. What should I do for non-rooted android device?

Comment: Follow the first link, and check for an ad blocker not requiring root? Right the first candidate of that list explicitly states "no root", and is available from my own F-Droid compatible repo: [Adguard](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.adguard.android). Same applies to [Seven Adclear](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.seven.adclear) :)

Comment: I used Ad-Blocker and AdGuard on non-rooted device. Both are not able to stop in-apps ads.

Comment: Sorry, then I cannot help further. I usually root my devices almost before unboxing them – and don't buy devices I cannot root.